# Avoid a repeating image for different resolutions (bootstrap 4)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Hi I have a working site with a logo included twice with different classes for different resolutions

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
<img class="d-none d-sm-block" width="279" height="70" src="logo.png">
<img class="d-block d-sm-none" width="232" height="58" src="logo.png">
#</a>
```

This seems okay and does what it says on the tin -

- hidden-xs-down = d-none d-sm-block
- visible-xs (only) = d-block d-sm-none

but is a bit untidy and I've been asked to get rid of the repeating image.  Is there a way to do this in one line ?

Comment: Not inline,but using css media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need CSS media queries for that, but it cannot be done inline.

```css
.navbar-img {
  width: 232px;
  height: 58px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-img {
    width: 279px;
    height: 70px;
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
  <img class="navbar-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats">
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been meaning to look at CSS media queries but haven't got around to it.  I'll move that higher up my list!